# How do I win the peekaboo minigame in Tomodachi Life?

Tags: tomodachi-life

How do I win the peekaboo minigame in *Tomodachi Life*? I've been trying to rub the baby's forehead, but it is not working. Is there a trick or cheat that will do it for me?

Comment: Everyone is right, guys.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Tomodachi Life wiki,](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Baby)

> The minigame for a 2-3 day old toddler is when the player has the option to play peek-a-boo or tickle them. It is random each time what action will calm them down. Three spots are good for tickling, the top of the head, the chin or the stomach. If the player does it wrong the baby will get angry and the player may lose the game and not get an item.

Hope this helps!

Let me know if this doesn't work for you or if this answer is wrong

Answer (score 1):

When at first you don't succeed, try, try again! If one doesn't work, try using rubbing the belly, tickling the chin, rubbing the forehead or playing peek-a-boo.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all, your problem is petting the *head.* You need to not even go to the peekaboo button, and try to tickle under the chin and tap it's nose.

Comment: As you can see, I have started answering my own questions

Comment: This didn't work for me, the baby got angry and ended up making me lose the minigame

Comment: try @user83601's answer.